# Can I use Native language support and Java code implementation in same project

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I want to use opengl es tlo form some geometries like arrows, triangle etc. and a camera preview class to display camera image in my android application. I want to know, if I can use native and Java classes both in a same class. I am just a beginner in Android application development. I will be grateful for your kind advise.
Thank You,
Arslan

Answer (score 1):

While you dont use any library not allowed like swing you can use native and java classes at the same time in a class

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to know of some way to integrate Java and C++ code together easily. JavaCPP does just that and it works for Android too:

http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/

(Disclaimer: I am the author.)

Comment: sir, I want to write some part of my application code in java and some part in opengl es. Can I do this ?